# Alignment in footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align items in my footer but I just can't seem to do it.

What I'm trying to do is add addresses up top i.e. home about etc

underneath that I'm trying to add privacy, legal etc with share buttons in the same line over to the right.

Below that I have a copyright, centered in the middle at the bottom.

I can get it almost there but not quite.

I'm trying to have the footer contain 3 rows. the top one contain site links like home, blog, etc the middle one to contain links like legal disclaimer etc but over in it's right corner I want the social icons and the last row to contain the copyright info.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Garrus/vf1gotkr/5/)

```css
footer {
    margin-top: 200px;
    height:20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#connect, #links-add {
    display:inline-block;
    height:20%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#links-add {
    width:20%;
}
#links-add p {
    margin-left:50px;
    color:#000000;
    text-align:left;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:'arial';
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
#connect.social-icons h3 {
    color:#000000;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:'arial';
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#links-add .links-footer {
    clear: both;
    margin-left:50px;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline;
}
#links-add .links-footer li, .links-footer li a {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-right:40px;
    vertical-align:top;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.links-footer li a:hover {
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
}
#connect .social {
    max-width:15%;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    display:inline;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
}
#connect .social li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:40px;
}
#connect .social li a {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:2px;
    width:34px;
    height:34px;
}
.copy-right {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.copy-right a {
    color: #000000;
    transition:0.3s all;
    -webkit-transition:0.3s all;
    -moz-transition:0.3s all;
    -o-transition:0.3s all;
}
.copy-right a:hover {
    color:#0000ff;
}
.social {
    display:inline;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
.social li a.facebook {
    background:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-72-72-7.jpg') no-repeat;
}
.social li a.twitter {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-72-72-7.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div id="links-add"> <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="links-add"> <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="links-add"> <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="links-add"> <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="links-footer">
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
        </li>
    </div>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
    </li>
    </div>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
    </li>
    </div>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
    </li>
    </div>
    <div id="connect">
         <h3>Chat with us</h3> 
        <ul class="social">
            <li><a class="facebook" href="#"> </a>

            </li>
            <li><a class="twitter" href="#"><img src=""> </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p class="copy-right">Website by Thor<a href="#">copyright info</a> &nbsp; &copy 2015</a>
    </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question but you are using CSS class selector `.links-footer` but the HTML has an ID attribute `id="links-footer"` which is probably causing some issues. Also the CSS rule `#links-add .links-footer li` does not match the HTML structure (`.links-footer` is not a descendant of `#links-add`)

Comment: You're trying to target the footer using ".footer", but the footer element is not a class. Either add class "footer" to the footer element or target the element instead of the class.

Comment: @andyb I've updated the fiddle to account for that. Thanks for pointing that out :) Also I fixed the footer being .footer.

Comment: @Garrus I have edited the question, updating the code to match the fiddle. Whilst doing this I also spotted that you are using `<li>` under a `<div>`. This in invalid HTML. You cannot have `<div>` as a parent of `<li>` - see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html

Comment: @andyb Thanks for that. That's a good read, I'm still getting my bearings with html and css and I have to say this site is great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrangement as per your need. Red border is for highlighting.! 
CSS

```
footer{
margin-top: 200px;
width: 100%;
background-color:#ddd;
border:1px solid red;
}
.row-2{border:1px solid red}
.row-1 li{display:inline-block}
.legal{float:left;}
.social{float:right;}
.legal li, .social li{display:inline-block;border:1px solid red}
.smm{border:1px solid red;}
.copy-right{text-align:center}
```

HTML

```
<footer>
<ul class="row-1">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
</ul> 
<div class="row-2">
    <ul class="legal">
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">legal</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="social">    
 <h3>Chat with us</h3>   
<ul class="smm">
    <li><a class="facebook" href="#"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-72-72-7.jpg" height="30"></a></li>
    <li><a class="twitter" href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-72-72-7.jpg" height=30> </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>


    <p class="copy-right">Website by Thor<a href="#">copyright info</a> &nbsp; &copy 2015</a></p>

</footer>
```

Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44ca6ep7/)**. Hope this help you.!!

Comment: It would be much more beneficial to future readers to explain what the original problems are and what your answer does to correct them.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for suggestion. Will take care that from now.! :)

Comment: @CodeRomeos That's perfect, thanks very much. If I wanted to make the second row stick to the bottom the way the social images do would something along the lines of vertical align:bottom; work?

Comment: But it is a nice answer nonetheless and should give the OP a good start at redesigning the code to remove the invalid HTML and CSS, so +1

Answer (score 1):

Two things I've noticed right away.

The background-color isn't working because in the CSS you're targeting the `.footer` class. You need to target the `footer` tag (note the lack of a full stop preceding it).

You shouldn't use IDs more than once in a document (use classes instead).

As for the layout I couldn't quite understand what you're saying. Get back to me and I'll help you out further.

Comment: That was a silly mistake, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the fiddle to account for it. I'm trying to have the footer contain 3 rows. the top one contain site links like home, blog, etc the middle one to contain links like legal disclaimer etc but over in it's right corner I want the social icons and the last row to contain the copyright info. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If only the footer color is your problem then what your doing wrong is your code.

```
.footer{
    margin-top: 200px;
    height:20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

what change you can do is

```
footer{
    margin-top: 200px;
    height:50px; //Give it a fixed height for now to check.
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#000;  
}
```

please let me know if its your solution and feel free to ask more if needed.

best regards.